# error in checking answer of hyperskill practice in IDE

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, ide

when I want to check my answer(hyperskill practice) in IDE, gradle do not finished and an error has accrued. the error is :
Failed to launch checking

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Gradle could not start your build.

> Cannot create service of type BuildTreeActionExecutor using method LauncherServices$ToolingBuildTreeScopeServices.createActionExecutor() as there is a problem with parameter #18 of type List.
> Could not create service of type ConfigurationCacheProblems.
> > io/usethesource/capsule/Set$Immutable

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s

Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

I change gradle dependency from release to master, invalidate cache, restart the intellij, restart computer, change java version, but my problem has not solved

Answer (score 0):

Go to a Gradle cache directory ~/.gradle/caches/ and move it somewhere else or delete it.

Then select JDK 17 as Gradle JVM in **Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle**.
After that, ensure that JDK 17 is selected as Project SDK in **File | Project Structure**.